# Apply a string replace to several columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe with several columns, two of which are strings of URIs with a final fragment such as:

`http://company.com/information#name`

`http://company.com/information#Company`

where I need to keep only "name" and "Company" URI fragments, and remove the string before the pound.

I have written the following function to do so on a passed dataframe , also passing a list of column names to act upon, and finally the string to remove from each of them:

```
def uri_fragment(DF: pd.DataFrame, COLUMN_LIST: list, URI_STRING: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    for DF_COLUMN in COLUMN_LIST:
        DF['DF_COLUMN'] = DF['DF_COLUMN'].map(lambda x: x.replace(URI_STRING,''))
    return DF
```

which I invoke as:

```
my_df = uri_fragment(my_df, ['class', 'type'], "http://company.com/information#")
```

to get the "class" and "type" dataframe columns cleaned up of the passed URI string.

but get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'DF_COLUMN'
```

What am I overlooking/misunderstanding?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a literal string in your function. You should remove the quotes:

```
DF[DF_COLUMN] = DF[DF_COLUMN].…
```

That said, a simpler method would be to use a regex. `map` will be quite slow:

```
for col in ['col', 'col2']:
    # here extracting any terminal fragment. You could also use
    # f'{URI_STRING}([^#]+)$' for limited matching
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract('#([^#]+)$', expand=False)
```

Also, another critic of your code, you are both returning `DF` and modifying it in place. You should do only one of the two.

Either don't return anything and modify in place, or return a new dataframe. For the second option, make a copy of `DF` by adding `DF = DF.copy()` in the beginning of the function.

Comment: Do I get your regex right?  capture From the first pound char excluded to one or more chars not being a pound until line end. So how would it behave with "blahblah#first#second" ? It would return "first#second" right? I probably want only "second"

Comment: No, the regex is anchored to the end due to `$`. So this is: get the last `#`, capture all character after it until the end

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in the string 'DF_COLUMN' as a key, rather than the variable DF_COLUMN from your loop. Since there is no column named 'DF_COLUMN', pandas is throwing a KeyError.